# Find & FindAll methods missing in MongoDB.Driver v1.3.1 for C#

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, mongo-collection

I am beginning to use MongoDB with C# and through following a few tutorials I have found that the methods Find & FindAll no longer exist in the latest versions.

Could somebody explain why and also, how would I now get the same functionality using v1.3.1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, they should be. At least I not see them at master branch on git [here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/Driver/Core/MongoCollection.cs) line 1655. In release notes for 1.3.1 [here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/master/Release%20Notes%20v1.3.1.txt) I also can't find any breaking changes.

It seems you can't find them because you have created mongodb collection in different way then before. Basically there is two approaches:

First approach is to specify exact type of document when getting collection:

```
var collection = db.GetCollection<ICanSpecifyTypeHere>("name")
//then collection has Find and FindAll methods
var result = collection.Find(Query.And());
```

Second approach is to specify type of document at find method :

```
var collection = db.GetCollection("name");
//in this case you should use FindAs<TypeOfDocument> and FindAllAs<TypeOfDocument>
var result = collection.FindAs<ICanSpecifyTypeHere>(Query.And());
```

I suppose that you have declared collection as in second approach and because of this don't see `Find` and `FindAll` methods.

Comment: Thanks for this. I will check and get back to you to mark this as the answer.

Comment: I wasn't declaring my variables using var. Thanks.